# Debugging Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to debug a firebase database connection (Android)? I'm using a really simple example (nothing big, just two listeners that listen on changes) that checks the value of `/.info/connected`. Most of the time, it returns false and the data is not synchronized. Sometimes it works, but not reliable.

There seems to be no problem with the internet connection - Auth and Storage works on the phone and a different phone in the same network can connect to the database just fine, so I think it has to do something with the phone. I'm testing with a Samsung XCover 3 (Lollipop, works) and a Wiko Sunset 2 (Kitkat, doesn't work).

The Wiko phone is really cheap, could that be a reason?

Are there any features to look deeper into firebase that could point me to the problem? The onCancelled method of my *ValueEventListener* doesn't get called and there are no log messages.

Comment: The Firebase debug logs are very detailed and would likely provide some explanation for the connection problem. Enable debug level logging using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` and examine the logcat output

Comment: Could you please explain better how the logs appear on logcat and if there is any chance to get them in the app? For example, catch them and use them to display the error to the user

Answer (score 6):

As @qbix said you can use

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.INFO)
```

There are multiple levels logs, from firebase src:

```
package com.google.firebase.database;

public interface Logger {
  public static enum Level {
    DEBUG,
    INFO,
    WARN,
    ERROR,
    NONE;

    private Level() {
    }
  }
}
```

More info at: [MakinGIANTS - Post](http://makingiants.github.io/blog/firebase-database-chat-experience/)