# firebase database download huge usage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a realtime database of only 200 B and my app has approx. 500 active users.

In the app I query the database to add data to some arraylist:

```
public class FirebaseApplication extends Application {

...

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

...

 //reference to the root of the cloud database
    mDatabase =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mNamesPoloSubRoot = mDatabase.child("PoloniexNames");

        //listen for change in the cloud. If there is some additional item, 
    //add it to the list populated from hard coded items.

                mNamesPoloSubRoot.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> gt = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
                        List names = snapshot.getValue(gt);

                        if( names == null ) {
                            //Log.v(LOG_TAG_FIREBASE,"No extra coins");
                        }
                        else {
                           // Log.v(LOG_TAG_FIREBASE,"extra coins!" );


                            additionalNamesPolo = new ArrayList<String>(names);
                            //attach the new coins at the bottom of the hard coded list
                            NamesPoloniexA.addAll(additionalNamesPolo);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG_FIREBASE, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                    }
                });

...

 }

}
```

I've 9 of such listeners. The data consumptions is approx. 100 MB every day! 
At this rate I will soon hit the 10GB/month limit. If I'm correct this data should be loaded every time a user open the app and every time I change remotely the data from server (this happens very rarely, like 2 times in a month). If opening the app loads, let's say, 1 KB, then this means that app should have been opened more than 100.000 times a day, and this it's not true by at least an order of magnitude.

My database is something like:

```
{
  "PoloniexAbbreviations" : [ "LGD", "PTOY", "PTOY" ],
  "PoloniexCurrencyPairs" : [ "ETH_LGD", "BTC_PTOY", "ETH_PTOY" ],
  "PoloniexNames" : [ "Legends", "Patientory", "Patientory" ]
}
```

Notice that many of the children called by the app are very often null (since there are no data to add remotely to the app), so the entire database can even be empty, but some data seems to be downloaded anyway (the size of the database, even if null, is not zero).

What I'm doing wrong? Or it's an issue of Firebase?

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Firebase synchronizes data at paths. Even when there is no data, it still needs to communicate the path back and forth. I highly recommend [enabling debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507630/209103) and checking logcat. It will give you insight into the communication that is happening, which translates to the bandwidth you see.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing similar problems.