# Firebase setValue() not triggered/working on Android 6 Marshmallow

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been working to solve this problem for like one & a half day and couldn't find any solution to it.

- Working on below Android Lollipop and others.
- Tried mostly all the solution.
- Even `FailureListener` is not triggered.

Code:

```
DatabaseReference mFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(constants.FIREBASE_URL+"rootssahaj/authGplus/users/teachers");
ProfileInformation pro= new ProfileInformation(email,personName,personPhotoUrll,personGooglePlusProfile,personPhotoUrllThumb,"true");

Log.e("SahajLOGwq", "CalledInside" +prefs.getBoolean("callProfileToFireBase",true)+" Email: "+EmailPref +pro+"  yo > "+pro.getUserNAME());
mFirebaseRef.child(EmailPref).child("profile").setValue(pro, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError != null) {
            Log.e("SahajLOGwq", "Data could not be saved. " + databaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            Log.e("SahajLOGwq", "Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

Logcat:

> 08-07 01:18:32.866 30547-30547/com.rana.sahaj.myyu E/SahajLOGwq: NOTICE__android  USER SIGNED IN
>
> 08-07 01:18:32.921 30547-30547/com.rana.sahaj.myyu E/SahajLOGwq: CalledOutsidetrue
>
> 08-07 01:18:32.922 30547-30547/com.rana.sahaj.myyu E/SahajLOGwq: CalledInsidetrue Email: narveshrana68 com.rana.sahaj.myyu.profile.ProfileInformation@e6ddcfd  yo > Narvesh Rana

*Rules for now

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,    
    ".write": true
  }    
}
```

*Edit:

this is what I found after Debug LogLevel of Firebase

> 08-07 18:22:08.275 8863-9013/com.rana.sahaj.myyu D/RepoOperation: set: /testforwrite
>
> 08-07 18:22:08.275 8863-9013/com.rana.sahaj.myyu D/DataOperation: set: /testforwrite true
>
> 08-07 18:22:08.289 8863-9013/com.rana.sahaj.myyu D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /testforwrite. Affected: /testforwrite
>
> 08-07 18:22:08.290 8863-9013/com.rana.sahaj.myyu D/RepoOperation: set: /rootssahaj/authGplus/users/teachers/narveshrana68/profile
>
> 08-07 18:22:08.291 8863-9013/com.rana.sahaj.myyu D/DataOperation: set: /rootssahaj/authGplus/users/teachers/narveshrana68/profile {
>                                                                       isTeacher=true
>                                                                       picurl=https://l400
>                                                                       picurl50DP=https://lh230
>                                                                       userEmail=na.om
>                                                                       userNAME=Narvesh Rana
>
> }
>
> 08-07 18:22:08.296 8863-9013/com.rana.sahaj.myyu D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /rootssahaj/

Comment: What's the problem you're having with this code?

Comment: the data isn't coming in database and what i remember it was working some days before but now suddenly it stopped and i haven't changed anything in the code!   and also the log statements inside the listener are not working.

Comment: Turn on debug logging and see if there's a problem with the connection.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817416/debugging-firebase-database

Comment: Since we don't know what `ProfileInformation` is, can you reproduce the problem by just setting a simple value to a known location. E.g. does `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(constants.FIREBASE_URL).child("testForWrite").set(true)` write to the database?

Comment: Can you update your code with ProfileInformation class?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried your code its not writing on database.

Comment: @AlexMamo as you can see in logcat at the end > "Narvesh Rana" is the output coming from **Profile Information** Class.

Comment: What is the error when you are trying to write data into the database?

Comment: there is no error that's the problem and its working in lollipop

Comment: @AlexMamo okie so there is some error in Debug loglevel of firebase. I have added that thing in question above..

Comment: Did you get this solved? because I'm having same problem with 6.0.1. Below than that is fine.

Comment: Actually it's solved on its own. I think the problem is from firebase side, I'm not sure about it but, this problem only occurred in one Mobile. I checked on the different devices with same version, the problem was not there. I had also talked with firebase support team but they were not able to help me out in it. But, later to my surprise, it was solved on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce this and get the same `D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /testforwrite. Affected: /testforwrite` on Lollipop when I am connected to wifi, disable the actual internet connectivity, and then re-enable internet connection (all with the device remaining connected to wifi network). After this, if I try to perform a setValue() write, about 18 minutes will pass before Firebase reconnects and the setValue() completes. I reached out to the Firebase team and was told this is expected behavior due to the Android OS basically neglecting to informing apps when the connection is restored.

<s>The only way to resolve in my experience is either disabling and re-enabling WiFi, or restarting the app (restarting the activity won't help).</s>

Firebase support got back to me and suggested calling goOffline() followed by goOnline() - I verified this immediately reconnects the Firebase database. What I do now is set a Handler with my own timeout for setValue(), since I can't seem to depend on DatabaseError being thrown with onComplete().