# firebase with android studio failing to store all data

Tags: android, sql, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue with storing all my data to firebase. I have a function to store data using a class, member as the data.

I write data to firebase, and it stores data, but only around 1/2 of the data I want to store. I have a log of data given by my SQL data cursor which I make an abstracted cursor window.

Then I loop this and store all entries. It only stores around the first half. Yet the data stored variable is correct on completion which means it has cycled through my database successfully

Therfore, something is wrong with my storage to firebase.

I want to store **172155** values to firebase. My data stored variable does equal this upon completion of my s mass store function but when I pull the data its limited to **81789** entries. I have inspected the json for this and that is all the data that is there.

My question is how should I go about storing this data correctly. If I try to store less data it works but I need to be able to store this size of data.

Why does this not work? `mDatareff_User.child(valueOf(i)).setValue(member);`

My write code is below:

```java
private void Mass_store_to_firebase() {
        Cursor data;
        data = BLE_DB.showData_Filtered_Log();
        data.moveToFirst();
        data_stored = 0;
        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "No data selected");
        }
        if (data.getCount() != 0) {
                //Cursor window fix and get data
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                CursorWindow cw = new CursorWindow("mass_store", 536870912);//16777216 broke
                AbstractWindowedCursor ac = (AbstractWindowedCursor) data;
                ac.setWindow(cw);
                ac.moveToFirst();//0

                if (ac.getCount() == 0)//No data selected
                {
                    Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "No data selected");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < ac.getCount(); i++) {
                    member.setT1_Data_string(ac.getString(1));//T1
                    member.setT2_Data_string(ac.getString(2));//T2
                    member.setT3_Data_string(ac.getString(4));//T3
                    member.setT4_Data_string(ac.getString(5));//T4
                    member.setPdiff_Data_string(ac.getString(6));//P1 data
                    member.setTime_string(ac.getString(7));

                    //Userdata_number_of_data = Userdata_number_of_data + 1;
                    //mDatareff_User.child(valueOf(Userdata_number_of_data)).setValue(member);//Increment max id count
                    mDatareff_User.child(valueOf(i)).setValue(member);//Use i to set the data.
                    data_stored++;
                    ac.moveToNext();
                }
                ac.close();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Stored mass data");//Log the event
            Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Stored mass data");//Inform the user
        }
    }
```

Sniplet of logcat

```
2020-06-04 14:52:44.128 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/EventRaiser: Raising 2 event(s)
2020-06-04 14:52:44.129 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/Connection: conn_0 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=p, r=54242, b={p=D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54238, d={t4_Data_string=2268, t2_Data_string=2268, t3_Data_string=2268, t1_Data_string=2268, pdiff_Data_string=-0.020000, time_string=2020-05-30 01:27:22 GMT}}}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.129 8113-8224/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"b":{"p":"D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54235","d":{"pdiff_Data_string":"-0.020000","t1_Data_string":"2268","t2_Data_string":"2268","t3_Data_string":"2268","t4_Data_string":"2268","time_string":"2020-05-30 01:27:19 GMT"}},"a":"d"}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.129 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 42807
2020-06-04 14:52:44.130 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54238. Affected: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54238
2020-06-04 14:52:44.130 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/RepoOperation: set: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54239
2020-06-04 14:52:44.130 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/DataOperation: set: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54239 {
      pdiff_Data_string=-0.010
      t1_Data_string=2268
      t2_Data_string=2268
      t3_Data_string=2268
      t4_Data_string=2268
      time_string=2020-05-30 01:27:23 GMT
    }
2020-06-04 14:52:44.130 8113-8224/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":54239,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.131 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/EventRaiser: Raising 2 event(s)
2020-06-04 14:52:44.131 8113-8224/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"b":{"p":"D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54236","d":{"pdiff_Data_string":"-0.020000","t1_Data_string":"2268","t2_Data_string":"2268","t3_Data_string":"2268","t4_Data_string":"2268","time_string":"2020-05-30 01:27:20 GMT"}},"a":"d"}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.131 8113-8224/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":54240,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.131 8113-8224/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"b":{"p":"D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54237","d":{"pdiff_Data_string":"-0.020000","t1_Data_string":"2268","t2_Data_string":"2268","t3_Data_string":"2268","t4_Data_string":"2268","time_string":"2020-05-30 01:27:21 GMT"}},"a":"d"}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.131 8113-8224/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":54241,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.137 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/Connection: conn_0 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=p, r=54243, b={p=D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54239, d={t4_Data_string=2268, t2_Data_string=2268, t3_Data_string=2268, t1_Data_string=2268, pdiff_Data_string=-0.010, time_string=2020-05-30 01:27:23 GMT}}}}
2020-06-04 14:52:44.137 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44992
2020-06-04 14:52:44.137 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54239. Affected: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54239
2020-06-04 14:52:44.137 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/RepoOperation: set: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54240
2020-06-04 14:52:44.137 8113-8223/com.example.firebase D/DataOperation: set: /D3:68:62:99:90:C3/54240 {
```

Comment: Do you get an exception when you try to store more records or does it just fail silently?

Comment: Fails silently I cant see a error log

Comment: Perhaps try upping the log verbosity for Firebase, ```setLoggingEnabled(true);``` it might present a clue.

Comment: Just call that In my oncreate method? Then it should post it to my log cat?

Comment: Calling it in the same place you do firebase initialisation should work. Then check logcat yes, it might get chatty with the number of records you are trying to write.

Comment: Also, I would recommend using WriteBatch for this. I believe it is designed for this usecase. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/WriteBatch

Comment: setLogginEnabled is undefined.

Comment: Are you using Firebase realtime database or Firestore? It might be a different method for RealTime database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817416/debugging-firebase-database

Comment: realtime database

Comment: @TomBailey write batch isn't for real time database unfortunately

Comment: You might be able to use updateChildren to emulate the same behaviour https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)

Comment: @TomBailey Your steps on getting debug logging are most helpful. Thanks for talking Thomas through that! On your other point: the equivalent of a batch write in Realtime Database would be a multi-location update indeed. I doubt that would make a difference here though. As the writes don't need to happen atomically as far as I can see, it would just add more memory overhead on the server, which reduces throughput.

Comment: @ThomasMorris Agreed with Tom that it would be useful to see the wire traffic. To enable debug logging, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level). I'd also recommend [attaching a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object,%20com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.CompletionListener)) to you `setValue(member)` call, to see if that shows a problem.

Comment: I've looked at the log and its writing a bunch of data quickly however, then it still writes but very damn slowly I can now see this in the logcat. So i think there is an issue with transfer speed with firebase at a certain size of data being uploaded.